# ARMA process and Impulse response

Tags: self-study, arima, impulse-response

I need to solve the following problem and I don't know where to look for relevant information.
Does anyone have a good source when ARMA processes are input/output to and LTI (Linear Time Invariant)?
Or perhaps some initial explanation on how to think about this problem? I do understand the relationship between autocorrelation, spectral density and impulse responses though.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi: The model you wrote is an ARMA(1,1) but I prefer the notation:

$ Y_t = \phi Y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t - \theta \epsilon_{t-1}$ where $\theta = \frac{3}{2} $ and $\phi = \frac{4}{25}$.

Using the lagged operator notation, we can simplify the above:
to $Y_{t}(1-\phi L) = \epsilon_t(1 - \theta L)$.

Therefore,  $Y_{t} = \epsilon_{t} \left[\frac{1-\theta L}{1-\phi L}\right]$

I'm not sure what the method is for writing this is an infinite sum of $\epsilon_t$. If you can figure that out,  the impulse response is straightforward.  Unfortunately, I'm at a loss right now for how to do that. Maybe a good night's sleep will lead to a revelation. If anyone knows, feel free to finish this answer off.

Actually, I worked on it on scrap paper and I think I got it.
The $(1- \phi L)$ in the bottom can be written as infinite series
in the top. So, we get

$Y_t = \epsilon_t (1-\theta L)(1 + \phi L + \phi^2 L^2 + \ldots +\phi^n L^n + \ldots )$ \

$ = \epsilon_t(1 + (\phi - \theta)L + (\phi - \theta)\phi L^2 +
(\phi - \theta) \phi^2 L^3 + \ldots + (\phi - \theta) \phi^{n-1}L^n$

But the series above is an infinite series, so it can be written as:

$ = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \psi_{j} \epsilon_{t-j}$

where $\psi_0 = 1$ and $\psi_j = (\phi - \theta)\phi^{j-1}$.

So, since the definition of the impulse response is the response due to the initial $\epsilon$ being 1.0 and then zero after that, the
IRF becomes:

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \psi_{j} $

Of course, you should put the actual numbers in for $\psi_{j}$.

If you have any questions, let me know. It's late and I could have made an algebra mistake somewhere but hopefully not a conceptual one.